# Python Clarifai confusion over setup

Tags: python, installation, clarifai

I'm trying to use clarifai with python and it tells me to run:

```
$ clarifai config
CLARIFAI_APP_ID: []: ************************************YQEd
CLARIFAI_APP_SECRET: []: ************************************gCqT
```

But where do I run this from?

I have a clarifai file in my python scripts folder,

[image]

If I open the clarifai file in nopetpad it has near the top

```
"""
the clarifai command line utility
Basically it helps to setup the environmental variables for the API Clients
"""
```

I have the environmental Path variables set up as follows

[image]

but if I try and run teh above from the comand prompt i get an error

[image]

[image]

So where/how do I run the above code from?

EDIT

Ive also tried the following

[image]

[image]

I am unsure if this has helped in any way?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for raising the problem! This issue has been fixed in python client version 2.0.8

Simply upgrade the client to v2.0.8 or higher.

Also it's recommended to report issues on https://github.com/Clarifai/clarifai-python/issues so the maintainer could catch the problem with resolution in a more timely manner.

Answer (score 1):

Try  `python C:\Python27\Scripts\clarifai config`

Comment: Thats not possible, there is no such folder clarifai. It is a file called clarifai not a folder

Comment: Ive just updated my question to show what happens when doing this, I have no idea what is happening when I do this, it looks like an error to me?

Comment: Yep, that's an error in the script you downloaded. Contact the creator.

Comment: Theres no error in the script it me thats doing something wrong, I just dont understand what Im supposed to be doing

Comment: @RunnerBean: There is an error in the script, that's what the stacktrace printed out by python is all about. The script tried to access the `HOME` environment variable, but it doesn't exist. If the script is meant to be cross-platform, it should be looking for a different env var when run on windows.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaround while this is fixed for Windows:

1) Open C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\clarifai\rest\client.py
2) In line 1748, change HOME to HOMEPATH
3) Save
4) Now you can do...

from clarifai.rest import ClarifaiApp
app = ClarifaiApp("YOUR_CLIENT_ID","YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET")

Make sure you replace the words with your actual client_id and client_secret

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
pip install clarifai

OR 

sudo pip install clarifai
```